# Inputting data in hash map of hash map in one loop or two single loops

Tags: java

I have a List which is of the following type: RepoID, Userid, Events counts(8 types)

example:

```
Repoid1, user1,8,1,0,2,3,4,5,9
Repoid1, user2,5,6,0,0,0,4,5,9
Repoid2, user1,5,0,5,2,3,4,5,1
Repoid3, user4,0,6,9,2,3,4,5,2
```

For each Repo, I want to find the count of each event type for a user.
I am using hashmap of hashmap but I do not want to use 2 loops as the file is too large. Is there a way to do it in a single loop or use 2 single loops?

I am currently using 2 loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) { //data is an arraylist
    String[] seq = data.get(i).split(",");
    String repo=seq[0];
    for (int j = 0; j < data.size(); j++) {
        seq = data.get(j).split(",");
        if(seq[0].equals(repo)){
            usermap.put(seq[1],"seq[2] + "," + seq[3] + "," + seq[4] + "," + seq[5] + 
                "," + seq[6]    + "," + seq[7] + "," + seq[8] + "," + seq[9]");
        } 
    }
    RepoUserMap.put(repo, EventsMap);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: updated in my question

Comment: Are `usermap` and `EventsMap` supposed to be the same thing?  Where are they declared?  Where are they initialized?  (We need to understand what you are trying to do here.  Your description is incomplete and so it your code.)

Comment: I have updated the code

Comment: Where is `usermap` declared???   And you have screwed up the indentation again.  I am rolling back your edit.  Please do it **properly**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem description is unclear, but given your input file, the following probably does what you need:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> repoUserMap = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) { //data is an arraylist
    String[] seq = data.get(i).split(",");
    String repo = seq[0];

    // Lookup the 2nd-level map, and create it if it doesn't exist yet.
    HashMap<String, String> userMap = repoUserMap.get(repo);
    if (userMap == null) {
        userMap = new HashMap<>();
        repoUserMap.put(repo, userMap);
    }

    usermap.put(seq[1],"seq[2] + "," + seq[3] + "," + seq[4] + "," + seq[5] + 
            "," + seq[6]    + "," + seq[7] + "," + seq[8] + "," + seq[9]");
 }
```

The middle section with the comment is the part you were missing (conceptually).

---

If there was a need to merge counts from multiple input lines for the same user and repo, then you would do it at the last line of the loop.  However that is not indicated in your code, your example or your description, so I am assuming it is not needed.

I would also point out that if you are doing this so that you can lookup the counts quickly, then you should be storing them as an array of integers, not as a string that needs to be split and parsed each time you lookup a count.

Comment: Maybe my description was not appropriate. What I want is to map repo with users(which will be mapped to the counts). The counts are the values that comes after the userid in the input. For every repoid i want a user mapped which will be further mapped to all the 8 event types count. Example: Repo1 {user1 -{8,1,3,2,1,2,3,4}} and so on for all the repoids.

Comment: You are just repeating yourself **without** addressing the point that I made.  So I assume that the assumption I made is correct.

Comment: I do not need to merge the counts for the user. I want it to be in the same format. 1 repo id should represent all the users belonging to it with the counts of all 8 event types.

Comment: Note: I am "playing hard ball" with this because in computer science it is very important that you provide a complete and clear statement of requirements.  If you just provide an example and a "hand wave, la la la" description, then the person trying to understand your requirements is liable to make *incorrect* assumptions about what you need ... and implement the wrong thing.  Fixing this (the consequences of the *inadequate* requirements statement) costs time and money.  Solution: get into the habit of always writing clear requirements.  Examples are not sufficient.

Comment: Based on your last comment.  I have guessed right about your requirements :-).   But it **was** a guess.

Comment: thank you so much. I will keep this in mind while posting next time. :)